# Gridview inside of form running at server throws "'GridView' must be placed inside aform tag with runat=server"

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I've seen a looot of questions about this and I've tried to overload/override `VerifyRenderingInServerForm` method and it isn't helping (the compiler complains if I try `overrides`).

To be sure:

In the `master` page, we have:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
```

so it definitely *is* inside a form/server tag.

The gridview has:

```
<asp:GridView
    ItemStyle-CssClass="Item"
    ID="grdInfo"
    runat="server"
    CssClass="grdCss"
    Width="100%"
    CellPadding="3"
    AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    HeaderStyle-CssClass="Header"
    RowStyle-CssClass="Item"
    AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="AltItem"
    AllowSorting="false"
    AllowPaging="false">
    ....
```

Unlike other people, I'm not trying to render excel. I am, however, attempting to bind to a enumerable `collection`:

```
Public Class colInfoSet
    Inherits CollectionBase
```

We use this type of object elsewhere without problems.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out what the problem is. When the master page and child page/controls are loaded, the grid isn't rendered because it has no rows. The grid is then retrieved via ajax and then populated.

Since it was not rendered when the page was rendered, it cannot be added to the control tree.

Hence it doesn't work.

The solution I will be going with is to use a repeater instead.